# Socket.io python client handling json args

Tags: python, socket.io

Excuse my ignorance, my first couple of days with python.

I have the follow python client that is listening for events from a nodejs server. I am using this library: https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client

```
import RobotArm
import time
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, BaseNamespace    

def statusChanged(*args):
    print(args)

socketIO = SocketIO('192.168.0.3', 3333)
socketIO.on('statusChanged', statusChanged)
socketIO.wait(seconds=1)

input('Press ENTER to exit\n')
```

Nodejs is sending:

```
socket.emit("statusChanged", { online: botOnline, battery: battery, charging: charging });
```

When I print args it outputs:

```
({u'battery': 50, u'charging': 0, u'online': u'1'},)
```

This apparently is being read as a tuple, not a dict which I need it as in order to parse the json. I read that the 'u's are indicating it is reading it as unicode, and I have no idea why there is a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `statusChanged(*args)` is defined to take an unspecified number of arguments. The parameter `args` is a tuple of all parameters used in calling it.

So the first actual parameter (the dictionary containing the data) can be accessed as `args[0]`

Comment: *bangs head* dammit I even tried args[0] at one point but must never have followed through and tested the conversion to dict() to check it was actually reading OK. Works great now thank you!!